# CSS: select previous sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a list and want to select the previous and next of the one I am hovering

```
<ul>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item1</li>
    <li>Item1</li>
</ul>
```

I am able to select the next sibling with the "+" selector. But is there a possibility to get the previous?

```
ul li:hover + li {
    color:red;
}
```

I already tried `ul li + li:hover` but it doesn't work.
Can't belief there is no tricky hack that I could use.

Sure I can do this easily through Javascript but I don't like using JS where I can get the same result with CSS.

Comment: there is no previous sibling selector in __css__

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no way to do this with pure CSS, if you really must select the previous sibling, you're going to have to resort of Javascript or suchlike.