# Highlight another elements on hover with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have a HTML which looks like this:

```
<p>
    <a id="foo" href="#bar">FOO</a><br/>
    <a id="bar" href="#foo">BAR</a><br/>
</p>
```

Now I want to highlight "BAR" when "FOO" is hovered, and vice versa. Is there a way to accomplish this in CSS3, or do I need jQuery?

I have tried this:

```
a#foo:hover ~ a[href="#foo"] {
    color:red;
    background-color:blue;
}
a#bar:hover ~ a[href="#bar"] {
    color:red;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

But the ~ operator only works forward, so it will work fine for the first link, but not for the second one.

See also here: http://jsfiddle.net/pw4q60Lk/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237143/css-select-previous-sibling

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pw4q60Lk/10/ Dynamic and short way for your case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, there's no previous sibling selector in CSS, this is to enable it to be applied on a single traversal of the document. But in your specific case you could take the following approach:

```
p:hover a:not(:hover) {
    color: red;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pw4q60Lk/2/

...although this does rely on the siblings completely filling the parent, as any hover over the parent alone will highlight both children.

Alternatively a (jQuery) script based approach would be:

```
$('a').hover(
    function() { $(this).siblings().addClass('highlight') },
    function() { $(this).siblings().removeClass('highlight') }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pw4q60Lk/12/

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector), there is no previous sibling selector.

With the help of Jquery you can achieve it using **hover()** and **mouseover()** function.

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <a id="foo" href="#bar">FOO</a><br/>
    <a id="bar" href="#foo">BAR</a><br/>
</p>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#bar").hover(function(){
    $('#foo').css({'color':'red','background-color':'blue' });
});
$("#bar").mouseout(function(){
    $('#foo').css({'color':'blue','background-color':'white' });
});

$("#foo").hover(function(){
    $('#bar').css({'color':'red','background-color':'blue' });
});
$("#foo").mouseout(function(){
    $('#bar').css({'color':'blue','background-color':'white' });
});
```

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/pw4q60Lk/1/)

Comment: make the code shorter by using toggleClass:
`$("#bar").hover(function(){
    $('#foo').toggleClass('blueBack');
});

$("#foo").hover(function(){
    $('#bar').toggleClass('blueBack');
});`

and put selector in your css:
`
.blueBack{
    background: blue;
    color: red;
}`

Answer (score 1):

As these answers mention, there is no pure previous css selector.

[CSS: select previous sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237143/css-select-previous-sibling)

[Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)

However, with jQuery you can do

```
$('a').hover(function(){
    $('a').not(this).addClass('hovered');
},
function(){
    $('a').not(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

using style

```
.hovered{
    color:red;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pw4q60Lk/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").on('mouseover', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.removeClass("hg");
    self.siblings().addClass("hg");
});

.hg {
    color:red;
}
```

**[JS Fiddle- Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pw4q60Lk/6/)**